# iOS - Cocos2d, Box2d or Chipmunk

Tags: ios, graphics, cocos2d-iphone, physics, chipmunk

I have to develop an app which has on screen 10 balls. When user shake the phone a sound will play and the ball have to move around the screen colliding each others without go out of bounds. I think i have to use cocos2d, box2d or chipmunk, but i don't know how can i do a thing like that. If someone have a tutorial, or some code it will be very appreciated.
I found another method that could be useful, it's `CGRectIntersectRect(obj1.frame, obj2.frame)`
but i think it isn't the correct way for my problem, is it right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Box2d or Chipmunk are supposed to take care of the collisions, so you don't have to use functions like `CGRectIntersectRect` to handle these kinds of events.
Start with some cocos2d tutorials to see how to display sprites on the screen and after that see some tutorials for your physics system of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Box2d and Chipmunk are physics engines that come WITH cocos2d, cocos2d is the graphics engine.

I suggest you go for Box2d as it not only provides collision detections (including with circle body shapes for your case) but also lets you handle all the physics etc. I've never used Chipmunk.

Answer (score 0):

There is a short Objective-Chipmunk tutorial that does most of what you are looking for already:
http://chipmunk-physics.net/tutorials/SimpleObjectiveChipmunk/